# How to cast to varchar and add % sign to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ive been pulling my hair out to get around this..how can i convert this to a varchar and add the % symbol to the results?

I have placed the code below of the query and have tried to cast it but keep getting errors that i don't know how to fix.  Can someone pleae make some suggestions on how to either simplify and prevent divide by zero issues also.

```
select 'Conversion Rate' as Type,
(
SELECT 
(
    COALESCE
    (                   
        CAST(CAST(nullif(t.ConvertedTrials,0) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) / (CAST(nullif(t.UnconvertedTrials,0) AS NUMERIC(18,2))) * 100 as decimal(10,2))
        , 
        0
    ) 
) AS Percentage

FROM (
    SELECT 
    UnconvertedTrials = (
        SELECT count(*) FROM 
        (
        select memberid from membership where discountcodeid = '79a7fd7c-9ebe-4ec0-8ac0-95ea274f1f64' Group by membership.memberid
        ) as a
        ), 
    ConvertedTrials = (
        SELECT count(*) FROM 
        (
            SELECT membership.memberid 
            FROM Membership, Package
            WHERE membership.PackageId = Package.Id
            AND Package.PackageTypeId != 1
            AND membership.memberid in (select memberid from membership where discountcodeid = '79a7fd7c-9ebe-4ec0-8ac0-95ea274f1f64')
            Group by membership.memberid
        ) as b
        )
) as t
) as Total
```

Comment: Can you show what your results would look like? Also, what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: What does the casting code look like?  Also, although you *can* add a percentage sign to a string, that's really more a concern for whatever the destination is for this data.  That's a display task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 'Conversion Rate' as Type,
RTRIM(CAST((
SELECT 
(
    COALESCE
    (                   
        CAST(CAST(nullif(t.ConvertedTrials,0) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) / (CAST(nullif(t.UnconvertedTrials,0) AS NUMERIC(18,2))) * 100 as decimal(10,2))
        , 
        0
    ) 
) AS Percentage

FROM (
    SELECT 
    UnconvertedTrials = (
        SELECT count(*) FROM 
        (
        select memberid from membership where discountcodeid = '79a7fd7c-9ebe-4ec0-8ac0-95ea274f1f64' Group by membership.memberid
        ) as a
        ), 
    ConvertedTrials = (
        SELECT count(*) FROM 
        (
            SELECT membership.memberid 
            FROM Membership, Package
            WHERE membership.PackageId = Package.Id
            AND Package.PackageTypeId != 1
            AND membership.memberid in (select memberid from membership where discountcodeid = '79a7fd7c-9ebe-4ec0-8ac0-95ea274f1f64')
            Group by membership.memberid
        ) as b
        )
) as t
) AS NVARCHAR(50))) + '%' as Total
```

your actual percentage is quite a large sub-query, it's hard to see how to enclose it in brackets - I had about 10 goes - is it any good yet?

- maybe it's easier to wrap the whole query in another select e.g

  `SELECT A,B FROM (<your query>) AS AQUERY`

(which should give exactly same results as your query) - THEN work on formatting B in the outer query

Here is my second way of doing it

```
    SELECT ORIGINAL.Type, RTRIM(CAST(ORIGINAL.Total as varchar(80))) + '%' AS Total 
FROM
(
select 'Conversion Rate' as Type,
(
SELECT 
(
    COALESCE
    (                   
        CAST(CAST(nullif(t.ConvertedTrials,0) AS NUMERIC(18,2)) / (CAST(nullif(t.UnconvertedTrials,0) AS NUMERIC(18,2))) * 100 as decimal(10,2))
        , 
        0
    ) 
) AS Percentage

FROM (
    SELECT 
    UnconvertedTrials = (
        SELECT count(*) FROM 
        (
        select memberid from membership where discountcodeid = '79a7fd7c-9ebe-4ec0-8ac0-95ea274f1f64' Group by membership.memberid
        ) as a
        ), 
    ConvertedTrials = (
        SELECT count(*) FROM 
        (
            SELECT membership.memberid 
            FROM Membership, Package
            WHERE membership.PackageId = Package.Id
            AND Package.PackageTypeId != 1
            AND membership.memberid in (select memberid from membership where discountcodeid = '79a7fd7c-9ebe-4ec0-8ac0-95ea274f1f64')
            Group by membership.memberid
        ) as b
        )
) as t
) as Total
) ORIGINAL
```